ISCSI_ERR_TCP_CONN_CLOSE: TCP connection closed) state (1)
I have an issue with my OpenStack running on Ubuntu 22.04. The storage and compute are on the same baremetal, and I use Cinder with an LVM backend.
The /var/log/syslog shows:
Jul 19 13:32:23 myhostname iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 45:0 error (1020 - ISCSI_ERR_TCP_CONN_CLOSE: TCP connection closed) state (1)
Jul 19 13:32:23 myhostname iscsid: Kernel reported iSCSI connection 44:0 error (1020 - ISCSI_ERR_TCP_CONN_CLOSE: TCP connection closed) state (1)
Jul 19 13:32:24 myhostname kernel: [34815552.624476]  connection45:0: detected conn error (1020)
Jul 19 13:32:24 myhostname kernel: [34815552.624500]  connection44:0: detected conn error (1020)
Jul 19 13:32:24 myhostname kernel: [34815552.624669]  connection44:0: detected conn error (1020)
Jul 19 13:32:25 myhostname iscsid: conn 0 login rejected: initiator error - target not found (02/03)
Jul 19 13:32:25 myhostname iscsid: conn 0 login rejected: initiator error - target not found (02/03)


Then I checked the connection iscsi related to log by command iscsiadm -m session:
tcp: [44] 10.126.127.6:3260,1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-ddd420f2-092f-4b8f-8492-3fb5b9821863 (non-flash)
tcp: [45] 10.126.127.6:3260,1 iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-a01b1f8e-6570-42f6-a4e3-57ce6794ddad (non-flash)

Then I check the volume-id in cinder:
ddd420f2-092f-4b8f-8492-3fb5b9821863 is not found
a01b1f8e-6570-42f6-a4e3-57ce6794ddad is exist but not attached to vm
I was trying to logout by command:
iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-ddd420f2-092f-4b8f-8492-3fb5b9821863 --portal 10.X.X.X --logout :
Logging out of session [sid: 44, target: iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-ddd420f2-092f-4b8f-8492-3fb5b9821863, portal: 10.x.x.x,3260]
iscsiadm: Could not logout of [sid: 44, target: iqn.2010-10.org.openstack:volume-ddd420f2-092f-4b8f-8492-3fb5b9821863, portal: 10.x.x.x,3260].
iscsiadm: initiator reported error (32 - target likely not connected)
iscsiadm: Could not logout of all requested sessions

Has anyone experienced this issue before?
I have try to logout the session related to error logs and restart the iscsid.service but it's not work. The question is how to solve the error? Should I restart the server?
